# My Nifty Scaffolds Aren't Nifty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I'm using the nifty generators for the first time (Rails 3.2.8) and I've created a simple scaffold with rails g nifty:scaffold post title:string body:string and then I generated a nifty layout too.  Then db:migrate fine and start up the server.    When I visit the page, I expected to see what I thought is the nifty default layout; a sort of light blue background and the form centered in a white div with rounded corners.  Isn't that the point of nifty?

All I see is the plain old rails default boring scaffold.   What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the css file here:

https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/blob/master/lib/generators/nifty/layout/templates/stylesheet.css